# MongoDB View performance

Tags: mongodb

We have a view in MongoDB that in its aggregation pipeline utilize a $lookup from base collection A to collection B as follow:

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': ‘B’, 
      'localField': ‘b_id', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': ‘B_lookup’
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      ‘b’: {
        '$first': '$B_lookup'
      }
    }
  }]
```

Both A.b_id and B._id are strings and indexed.
Running queries in the view, with a large amount of documents get very slow in time (for ~120000 documents takes ~26 seconds).
We can see in the ‘Explain Plan’ tab, that the most time consuming is the $lookup stage:

```
{
    "stages": [{
        "$cursor": {
            ...
        },
        "nReturned": 151976,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 348
    }, {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "B",
            "as": "B_lookup",
            "localField": "b_id",
            "foreignField": "_id"
        },
        "nReturned": 151976,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 18364
    }, {
        "$addFields": {
            "b": {
                "$first": ["$B_lookup"]
            }
        },
        "nReturned": 151976,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 18365
    }],
    "ok": 1
}
```

**Question**:
Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: You can try the aggregation without the `$addFields` stage. The `$lookup` itself can specify a _pipeline_ with the `$match` and then a `$limit: 1`.

Comment: @prasad_ I removed the $addFields stage but performance is still the same. Any other idea?

Comment: If A or B documents are relatively small maybe embedding A in B or B in A  is a better option ...